# use systemd-escape in an interavtive way

Tags: bash, pipe

If we use `systemd-escape SomePassword`, the password will be stored in bash_history file. Is it possible to use it in an interactive way?

`cat | systemd-escape` fails as `systemd-escape` expects the input data as parameter and not standard input.

Comment: will not `systemd-ask-password` do what you ask?

Comment: Oh @bac0n , I didn't know about this. But no, it does not escape special chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read one line from standard input:

```
$ read -rsp "password: " && \
  systemd-escape "$REPLY"; unset REPLY
```

Using systemd-ask-password with systemd-escape:

```
$ systemd-escape "$(systemd-ask-password)"
```

Comment: in zsh, I get: `read: -p: no coprocess`

Comment: remove -p in zsh